# Laravel Mutator causes SQLSTATE general error 1364 field 'x' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-backpack

**I've been investigating the issue and i've found what caused this. See the bottom of question**

I'm on Laravel 5.4 and using BackPackForLaravel as my admin interface.

I have a `GenreTableMigration` like bellow :

```
Schema::create('genres', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('slug')->default('');
    $table->string('image');
    $table->enum('status', ['PUBLISHED', 'DRAFT'])->default('PUBLISHED');
    $table->boolean('featured')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

Notice the `image` column is non-nullable and has no default value.
In my model `Genre` theres this:

`protected $fillable = ['slug', 'name', 'image', 'status', 'featured'];`

I also have mutator for `image` column in my model:

```
/**
 * Store Image
 */

public function setImageAttribute($value)
{
    $attribute_name = "image";
    $disk = "public";
    $destination_path = "Albums";

    // if the image was erased
    if ($value == null) {
        // delete the image from disk
        \Storage::disk($disk)->delete($this->image);

        // set null in the database column
        $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = null;
    }

    // if a base64 was sent, store it in the db
    if (starts_with($value, 'data:image')) {
        // 0. Make the image
        $image = \Image::make($value);
        // 1. Generate a filename.
        $filename = md5($value . time()) . '.jpg';
        // 2. Store the image on disk.
        \Storage::disk($disk)->put($destination_path . '/' . $filename, $image->stream());
        // 3. Save the path to the database
        $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = $destination_path . '/' . $filename;
    }
}
```

And my `GenresTableSeeder`:

```
$path = base_path('seeder-resources/GenresPhotos');

DB::table('genres')->delete();

$genres = [
    [
        'name' => 'Pop',
        'image' => "$path/Pop.jpeg",
        'status' => 'PUBLISHED',
        'featured' => mt_rand(0, 1),
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    ],
];

foreach ($genres as $genre) {
    $this->command->info(print_r($genre));
    Genre::create($genre);
}
```

When i use `GenreCrudController` and use the `Add Genre` button everything works fine and the row is created but when i try to seed the table i get the following error on my console.

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'image' doesn't have a default v  
  alue (SQL: insert into `genres` (`name`, `status`, `featured`, `created_at`  
  , `updated_at`, `slug`) values (Pop, PUBLISHED, 0, 2017-03-10 08:43:15, 201  
  7-03-10 08:43:15, pop))
```

Even if i set the `image` value (which is a string column) in `$genres` array to `Anything`. I also tried to seed eloquently like below:

```
$genre = new Genre();
$genre->name = 'Pop';
$genre->image = "anything";
$genre->status = 'PUBLISHED';
$genre->featured = 1;
$genre->save();
```

Still the same error in console. Does anyone have any idea?

**Update**
So i've changed the `image` column name to `somestring` and oddly enough the seeder worked. I tried to put the `image` column in another table, let's say `Articles` table and added `'image' => 'test'` in my `ArticlesTableSeeder` and again it worked. Then i've added the same mutator in `Article` model and BOOM! the `image` output in my table was NULL. does anybody have any clue why my `setImageAttribute` mutator causes this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've found that the Mutator `setImageAttribute` only accepted Null or base64 `$value` and i was trying to seed Image File and when it failed i was trying to seed a string. i came up with this Mutator instead and it worked perfectly:

```
/**
 * Store Image
 */
public function setImageAttribute($value)
{
    $attribute_name = "image";
    $disk = "public";
    $destination_path = "Genres";

    // if the image was erased
    if ($value == null) {
        // delete the image from disk
        \Storage::disk($disk)->delete($this->image);

        // set null in the database column
        $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = null;
    } // if a base64 was sent, store it in the db
    elseif (starts_with($value, 'data:image')) {
        // 0. Make the image
        $image = \Image::make($value);
        // 1. Generate a filename.
        $filename = md5($value . time()) . '.jpg';
        // 2. Store the image on disk.
        \Storage::disk($disk)->put($destination_path . '/' . $filename, $image->stream());
        // 3. Save the path to the database
        $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = $destination_path . '/' . $filename;
    } // else if a file was sent
    else {
        // 0. Convert the image to jpeg format
        $image = \Image::make($value)->encode('jpg', 100);
        // 1. Generate a filename
        $filename = md5($value . time()) . '.jpg';
        // 2. Store the image on disk
        \Storage::disk($disk)->put($destination_path . '/' . $filename, $image->stream());
        // 3. Save the path to databse
        $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = $destination_path . '/' . $filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who tried to help. I'll accept this answer one 16 hours is passed.

Answer (score 0):

In your migration please change like below and try :

```
Schema::create('genres', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name')->nullable();
    $table->string('slug')->nullable()->default('');
    $table->string('image')->nullable();
    $table->enum('status', ['PUBLISHED', 'DRAFT'])->default('PUBLISHED');
    $table->boolean('featured')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

Please provide nullable() to your string fields.

Comment: I guess it doesn't have to be nullable if you set it manually but then again I'm no expert. i tried your code and even though i got no error this time but `image` is `NULL` in my db. This is what console showed when seeding:  Array
(
    [name] => Pop
    [image] => test
    [status] => PUBLISHED
    [featured] => 0
    [created_at] => 2017-03-10 09:45:29
    [updated_at] => 2017-03-10 09:45:29
)

Answer (score 0):

First: if you use default value in database, please do it like(with nullable): 
`$table->string('slug')->nullable()->default('');` 
else laravel doesnt create correct new records.

Second: try to use `'image' => $path.'/Pop.jpeg'`

Im not sure, but maybe you must escaping string `'image' => $path.'\/Pop.jpeg'`

Comment: for your first answer, i did that as @Muthu17 suggested. for your second answer `image` would be NULL even if i try `'image' => 'test'. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711020/laravel-sqlstate-general-error-1364-field-x-doesnt-have-a-default-value#comment72544029_42711342